# MSBuild outputting incorrect DateTime.UtcNow format

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

For my Version tag in csproj I've the following:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Version>
            $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Year).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("MM")).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("dd")).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("HHmm"))
        </Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

But it outputs like so: `Vysn.Voice.2020.1.9.309.nupkg` for nuget packages and when I get version info from assembly: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`.

But when I do

```cs
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var informationalVersionAttribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>();

Console.WriteLine(informationalVersionAttribute.InformationalVersion);
```

It outputs the proper DateTime string: `2020.01.08.1018`. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong when specifying the version but I want it to output the version properly: `2020.MM.dd.HHmm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But it outputs like so: Vysn.Voice.2020.1.9.309.nupkg for nuget packages*

This is a behavior by design.

1. First of all, The `Vysn.Voice` is so called **package identifier**, and the `2020.1.9.309` is named **package version**. As the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#package-versioning) describes:

   > A specific package is always referred to using its **package identifier** and **an exact version number**

   - By default, the **package version** matches the `Version`. As a result, you can change the package version by custom the `<Version/>` element in `*.csproj`. Be aware **the package version will NOT affect the package identifier**.
   - By default, the package identifier matches the metadata of `<PackageId>Vysn.Voice</PackageId>` in the `*.csproj` file. If `<PackageId/>` is not specified or empty, it will use the `AssemblyName`. For more details, see [Package Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#packageid).
2. Also, note the version number in `<Major>.<Minor>.<Build>` should be an **`Integer`**. And when a project is packaged using `NuGet`, the **leading zeroes** in the version numbers are always **removed** from the `Major`, `Minor`, and `Build` part. So instead of getting `2020.01.09`, you'll get `2020.1.9`. This behavior is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#normalized-version-numbers).
3. Finally, when you invoke

   ```
   assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
   ```

   you're actually trying to get the [`InformationalVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute.informationalversion?view=netcore-3.1)  which is different from `Version` or `PackageVersion`. `InformationalVersion` might **contain any string**. This `InformationalVersion` matches the `Version` by default and might looks like `2020.01.09.0704` (Note there will be some leading zeros.)